# How can I change the value that is connected to select change in dynamic form using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I was trying to make a form, which has two elements, one select item and one input price, select option are stored in database, so I retrieve it and display it.

User can add new row with same elements when button add is clicked, when the select option is changed, I am using ajax to get the price from database and displayed it in the text input.

It all worked fine with the first row but when user add new row I cannot retrieve the price and get the following message

> "the specified value "NaN" is not a valid number. The value must match
>   to the following regular expression:
>   -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?"

How can I solve this problem or is there is another way to change the value of input using the row id

```
<table id="tab_logic">
    <tr id='row0'>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control item" name="item[]" required>
            <?php 
                $items = "SELECT itemCode, itemName FROM items";
                $itemslist = $conn->query($items);
                while($row = $itemslist->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row["itemCode"] . "'>" . $row["itemName"]. "</option>" ;
                }
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name='price[]' class="form-control price" required/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='row1'></tr>
</table>
<button id="add_row" class="btn btn-default">Add Row</button>

<script>

function get_price(sel, item) 
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "getData.php",
        data: {itemCode: sel },
        success: function(data) {
            $(item).find("input").val(data.price) 
        },
    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //add new row when add buttomn clicked 
    var i = 1;

    $("#add_row").click(function(){
        var a = i-1;

        $('#row' + i).html( $('#row' + a).html() )
                   .find('td:first-child')
                   .html(i+1);
        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="row' + (i+1) + '"></tr>');
        i++; 
    });

    //when selected item change get parent and call function 
    $('#tab_logic select').on('change', function() {
        var item = $(this).parent().parent();

        get_price(this.value, item);
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: What line is giving you the error message?

Comment: error appear on the new rows, the function works only on the first row

Comment: which line of code specifically is throwing the error?

Comment: the message appears not on specific line but on new rows added dynamically

Comment: No, an error message must be triggered by a specific line of JavaScript code. The browser console will tell you which line caused the error. I'm not talking about your HTML rows. Unless you mean this is a validation error which actually appears somewhere within the web page (rather than in your console)? Please be clear about where you are seeing this error.

Comment: jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4

Comment: you should be able to trace it back to a line of _your_ code. There will be a stack trace. If you can't work it out, use the debugger to step through the JS code line by line when you run it, until you stop on the line which produces the error. I ask this because it's far from clear, just by looking at the code shown, what would be producing this.

Comment: Can you update your html so that it includes the 'tab_logic' element and 'add_row' button?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it finally, the problem was that get_price is only called one time on first change so I solved it using this way by calling the function onclick

```
    <select class="form-control item" name="item[]" onclick="get_price(this.value,$(this).parent().parent());" id='1' required>
```